# Update hierarchical data in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have an array of objects in my document in MongoDB which is deeply nested its structure is like this:-

```
items : [{
       filename:'abc',
       items:[{
            filename:'qwe',
            items:[{
                filename:'asdasd',
                items:[{......]}}
```

I am using this structure to make a file explorer in my frontend in react, now the problem is the depth of this nested object can be as much as the user wants because the user can create files inside the file as much as he/she wants, but I don't know how can I update a file which is deeply nested and I don't know at which level. If you can suggest some other architecture that would be fine too.

Answer (score 0):

firstly you can create items collection which has id like that:

```
  {
    "_id": Id("item1"),
    "filename": "abc",
    "parent": null // no parent since it's at the top level
  },
  {
    "_id": Id("item2"),
    "filename": "def",
    "parent": Id("item1") // reference to parent item1
  },
  {
    "_id": Id("item3"),
    "filename": "gdj",
    "parent": Id("item2") // reference to parent item2
  }
]
```

then this collection must be insertin of mongodb documents via items id:

```
{
  "_id": Id("blablabla"),
  "items": [
    {
      "$ref": "items",
      "$id": Id("item1")
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but there is a problem with this approach actually if I follow this approach then while getting data in frontend I will need to query each id one by one and I don't think that is a good idea.

Comment: no, you will put all items on the endpoint like that /items then take all of them as a json format to be retreived from frontend

Comment: If i am gonna do that i dont understand why i am maintaining the nested object? I can just maintain this items collection, but i am not doing that because this nested object helps me to show a nested flow in frontend by recursively calling my component in react.

Comment: @Spidy [`"$graphLookup"`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/graphLookup/) could be a useful stage if you are considering this data model.  The MongoDB server will perform the recursive search on the collection.